# Selecting data from multiple tables in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm am in the middle of creating my first, substantial .NET MVC application. I have come across a problem and I am not quite sure the proper way to go about it.

In my application I have quite a large database. For a number of features I need to select data from up to 5 tables and send it back to the view, and I am not quite sure how to go about it since view takes either Models or View Models?

I understand the concept of View Models quite well, but is creating one every time I need to send data from multiple tables the only solution to this? And if so could anyone tell me the best practices when doing it

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I want to be clear.  You're already able to fetch the data from the database.  Your question centers around providing that data to the client?

Comment: Hi. Yes I have already fetched data from the db and sent it to the view. I am just unsure how to do this from multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'll have to have a View Models per view. I work on application with about 600 views and we tried re-cycling view models and it ended up in tears. Now there is a model for each view (mostly).

To send data from multiple tables you'll need to run joins on your tables and select into a view model.

Here I presume you use Entity Framework:

```
public class ComplexViewModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String Level { get; set; }
}

var db = new MyDbContext();
var result = from name in db.Names
             join category in db.Categories on name.CategoryId equals category.CategoryId
             join level in db.Levels on category.LevelId equals level.LevelId
             select new ComplexViewModel()
                {
                    Name = name.Name,
                    Category = category.CategoryName,
                    Level = level.LevelName,
                };
return result.ToList();
```

More examples of joins can be found are [recommended to review.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9)